# How to Split Screen Emacs and Terminal

Tags: linux, emacs, splitview

everyone.

I use PuTTY and I am wondering if it's possible to open an emacs text file in split screen with the terminal window.

I looked everywhere for the answer, but all I've found is how to have two emacs windows open, and I would like to be able to see and switch between the terminal window and an emacs file.

Thanks.

Comment: You can always run a terminal inside of Emacs, and then use Emacs' window splitting features.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the region feature in [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) rather than using the split screen within emacs... but then you might want to rebind the escape key in screen.

Comment: I'll second this answer, screen (or [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net)) is what you're after.

If you're using tmux then something like the following in your _tmux.conf_ file will help (three separate lines):

set -g prefix C-q <nl>
bind-key C-q last-window <nl>
bind-key q send-prefix <nl>

This will rebind 'C-q' to be the prefix to talk to tmux (for splitting windows etc), and makes 'C-q C-q' a convenient binding for flipping between sessions.

In tmux, the 'C-q ^' command will split the window horizontally, and 'C-q "' will split the window horizontally.